# What is the difference between greedy and best-first search algorithms?

Tags: graph, a-star, greedy, heuristics, best-first-search

- Best-first search - a search that has an evaluation function f(n) that determines the cost of expanding node n and chooses the lowest cost available node
- Uninformed search - has no knowledge of h(n)
- Informed search - has knowledge of h(n)
- Greedy search - is best-first, can be informed or uninformed, f(n) does not contain g(n)
- Uniform cost search - is best-first, is not greedy, is uninformed, f(n) = g(n)
- A* search - is best-first, is not greedy, is informed, f(n) = g(n) + h(n)
- Greedy best-first search - is best-first, is greedy, is informed, f(n) = h(n)

Is this correct? Can someone give concrete and all-encompassing definitions for these terms? It seems that "greedy" and "best-first" are often used interchangeably.

Even Wikipedia has conflicting definitions...

[Greedy algorithm - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm#Examples):

> Dijkstra's algorithm and the related A* search algorithm are verifiably optimal **greedy** algorithms

[Best-first search - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search):

> The A* search algorithm is an example of a best-first search algorithm, as is B*. Best-first algorithms are often used for path finding in combinatorial search. **Neither A* nor B* is a greedy best-first search, as they incorporate the distance from the start in addition to estimated distances to the goal.**

Is it that A* is greedy, A* is best-first, but A* is not greedy best-first?

Someone please sort all these terms out...

Comment: I thought A* was best-first plus the heuristic 'h' . You can turn A* greedy by turning down the H weight. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374308/is-the-greedy-best-first-search-algorithm-different-from-the-best-first-search-a for more..